# Creating static library which depends on other static library (RestKit)

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I followed the following tutorial to create a static library:

https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework/#developing-the-framework-as-a-dependent-project

It all works until I try to incorporate the RestKit into my static library. There I am completely lost. Am I supposed to include the RestKit library into my static library or only in the App which will use my library?

If I don't include RestKit in my library, I can't compile it as it depends on another library (RestKit) so what would be workaround for this?

I tried to look everywhere but haven't found a good step by step tutorial to create a static library which itself depends on other static libraries.

Comment: I have been running into the same issue. I was able to get the code to compile by adding a restkit reference to both the static library and the project referencing my library using cocoapods. However, not everything seems to work. I have lost the ability to call extension methods, though the compiler still seems to think they are there.

Comment: I think I am going to have my static library reference RestKit, and then have that library provide an abstracted interface to my other projects to make network calls. This will be better in the long run, in case RestKit changes its interface (or if I decide to use a difference library in the future).

Answer (score 1):

What I did to get this working was to add RestKit to my static library using their git-submodule instructions [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule). Then I performed the exact same steps on the projects that were going to use my static library EXCEPT:

1. I did not add RestKit to the "Target Dependency" section of the Build Phases
2. I did not add the libRestKit.a to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section. All other references still needed to be added.

I was then able to reference RestKit in both my static library and my iOS project.

***COCOAPODS MEGA HACK***

I was able to get this working with cocoa pods, but it will only work if this is your only cocoapods project. I started with all of my projects in a single workspace. Then I had my single podfile install RestKit to my static library and all projects that were going to reference my static library. Then for each project that I wanted to reference my static library I removed the pod reference under "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Everything was then working as expected.

As you can expect, this would probably break all other pod references (unless you managed them all through that one static library), but it does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Shorty after asking the question I finally managed to get it working here the steps if someone has a similar problem:

Create an actual app as explained int [this](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework/#developing-the-framework-as-a-dependent-project) section. After adding your library add all the other libraries you use to the application. (In my case it was the RestKit framework, add it as a submodule and not with cocoapods as with cocoa pods it didn't manage to get it to work properly).

After adding all your libraries, follow the third party libraries instruction for modification for the application and make the same modification for your static library.

e.g. for Restkit I had to add 
`-ObjC -all_load` 
to the **Other Linker Flags** and add 
`"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers"` 
to the **Header Search Path** inside my static library.

I still couldn't build as the `<RestKit/Restkit.h>` wasn't found, so I needed to change the build order of the frameworks to assure that Restkit was built before my library.

This is done inside the edit Scheme of the build menu. Make sure that all the dependent libraries are on top of your library (if your static library or the dependent libraries aren't already in there add them with the '+')

[image]

Afterward everything worked for me. I am not sure if this is the best method to do it or if it would be better to include the third party library inside your statistic library.

**Update** I still run into problems when trying to build my library, if someone has a better solution or can shed some light on how to create a static framework which depends on other frameworks I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you got any thing for this?

Comment: I changed my setup to now use Cocoapods and their implementation of libraries. I can now use a local git repo for my library and integrate it in all my projects. if you need help setting it up let me know